# build and testing with TFS 2013 and Selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm looking help for Microsoft Team foundation server  2013 , in fact i want to integrate selenium script with auto build. when build is deployed my selenium script run automatically on new build,

I'm new to Team foundation server so i don't have much idea about integration selenium script , please explain in detail so that i can follow exact steps.

My script is placed at Team foundation server   repository , do i need to compile my selenium script with auto-build or no need to compile

Comment: post build or pre build ?

Comment: I'm facing issue in Post Build , build is created and deployed successfully when it come to Test , No Test and No Data coverage found.

Comment: Patrick, Team foundation server 2013 support for test the build using Selenium because i have seen most of help available for TFS2015 ?

Comment: What's your selenium script wrote with? C#?

Comment: Yes Eddie , its written with C#

Answer (score 0):

You just need to build the selenium project and then run the test with it.

Comment: I have build the selenium project but when build created successfully, in result displaying No Test Result or No Test coverage , i think TFS did not recognize the test even i mention Test.dll in test process.

Comment: Can you share your build definition settings? Did you point to the test assembly in it?

Comment: I cant upload the image  due to points limitation so providing you test process configuration   C:\Download\AutoMation\Test\seleniumTest\bin\Debug\*Test*.dll; **\*Test*.appx     options: Enable Code coverage